# Understanding BinLogDiskUsage Metric behavior

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, disk-space, monitoring, binlog

We are using AWS-RDS. The following is the screenshot of how the binary log disk usage has varied over the last 6 weeks.

[image]

The log retention period is 3 days. Tables are optimized and archived once a week. We were expecting the BinLogDiskUsage to be almost constant(assuming periodic purging of logs by AWS ) with spikes during archival tasks.

Can anyone explain this wavy nature of the graph?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_binlog_size';`

Comment: @RickJames The value of max_binlog_size is 134217728. SHOW BINARY LOGS showed 1447 files with the average file size being 1396626. However, there was one file with size 70067577.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Long-winded, but incomplete, answer)

The graph moves up and down rather smoothly.  This puzzled me.  With your latest numbers, I can explain *some* of what is going on.

Data is written to the binlog until it exceeds `max_binlog_size` (128M, in your case).  At that point, a new binlog file is created.

Slave(s) pull the data from the binlogs continually, and *usually* keep up.  There is, however, no feedback to let the Master know when *all* the Slaves are finished with a binlog file.  So, instead, there is some other mechanism for deleting old binlogs.

With `expire_logs_days` (3 in your case), binlog files older than that many days will be deleted.

Normally your 2GB (1447*1396626) would occupy about 16 binlog files (that /134217728).  And the graph would show distinct drops of 128MB every so often.

The only thing I can think of for leading to 1447 binlogs instead of 16 is spurious `PURGE` commands.  Please run these:

```
 SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%purge%';
 SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
```

The quotient will say how many purges per second.  Normally, this will be close to zero.  But your system seems to have several per hour.  So, I have converted the mysterious graph into "Why is `PURGE` being performed so often."

(See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning if you would like deeper analysis of `STATUS` and `VARIABLES`.)

**More**

1447 binlogs with `purge_logs_days_seconds = 500` (5 minutes).  This says there are usually 1 or 2 binlogs being purged each time.  The graph shows a *weekly* pattern.  One part of the week is quite busy -- adding a lot to the binlogs while purging 3-day-old files that have much less.  This makes the graph go up.  Ditto for down.  Flat says that you are adding at the same rate you are deleting.

I would guess there was a lull in traffic, or a national holiday, during the last week of May?

There are still contradictions in what little data you have provided.  1447 and purge after 3 days would say 3 minute interval, not 12/hour.  Or 5 days, not 3.  Also, max binlog size of 70MB (out of 128MB max) would imply that a purge cycle never purges more than 1 file.

The system has a rhythm; nothing seems terribly wrong.

Comment: Yes, the instance is purging almost 12 times an hour. As far as I know, PURGE command deletes binary logs. Should not it decrease the binary log count? Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SubrataDas - I'm still missing enough clues to fit the pieces together.  I added to my Answer.  `PURGE` should delete file(s) each time it is run; based on your data, Some of your data says there is never more than 1 file deleted; some says more than one.  Normally, binlogs grow to the max, but that is not happening; still no clue of why.

Comment: Is it normal to have such regular purging? Can it have any adverse effect?

Comment: @SubrataDas - The frequency of purging should not matter.  Perhaps there is frequent `FLUSHing`.  Frequent flushing should not matter, either.  Both are unusual.